# HTML dice problem (not able to apply css as per requirement)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to run this code by first time after refresh its going well but after 1 click its not applying CSS as per requirement

**This is Problem Statement**

THROW DICE
Problem Statement: Throw Dice
You and your two other team members are doing your construct week project. An issue arises in your project and all three of you come up with a solution. All the three solutions are feasible and each one of you wants to implement his own solution. Hence all of you decided to roll a dice and whoever gets the maximum score will implement his solution. But the problem is you cannot roll a dice online, so you, being an active team member, decided to make an app with three dice showing a random number between 1 to 6 as described below.

Description :-
Create an Index.html file
Create three “DIV”, which will represent three dice and show a random number between 1 to 6.
First will represent score for Member A
Second will represent score for Member B
And third will represent score for Member C
Make a button with text content “ROLL THE DICE”
On pressing the button all the three dice should roll and show a random number between 1 to 6.
Make a “DIV” at the top which will show the winner
Things to follow :-
First dice will have id “member-1”.
Second dice will have id “member-2”.
Third dice will have id “member-3”.
Roll the dice button will have id “roll”.
The winner showing div will have id “winner”
The winning dice will be in color green.
The Second scorer dice will be in yellow
And the dice who scored least should be in red.
In case of draw make the dice scoring equal appear blue.

```js
document.getElementById("roll").addEventListener("click", rollTheDice)

function rollTheDice() {
  var score1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  document.getElementById("score1").innerText = score1;
  var score2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  document.getElementById("score2").innerText = score2;
  var score3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  document.getElementById("score3").innerText = score3;
  if (score1 === score2 && score2 == score3) {
    document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = "Draw";
    document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "blue");
    document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "blue");
    document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "blue");
  } else if (score1 === score2 || score1 === score3 || score2 === score3) {
    if (score1 === score2) {
      document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = "Draw";
      document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "blue");
      document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "blue");
      if (score3 > score1) {
        document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "green");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
      }
    } else if (score1 === score3) {
      document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = "Draw";
      document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "blue");
      document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "blue");
      if (score2 > score1) {
        document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "green");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
      }
    } else if (score2 === score3) {
      document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = "Draw";
      document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "blue");
      document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "blue");
      if (score1 > score2) {
        document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "green");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
      }
    }

  } else {
    if (score1 > score2 && score1 > score3) {
      document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = 1;
      document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "green");
      if (score2 > score3) {
        document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
        document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "red");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "red");
        document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
      }
    } else if (score2 > score1 && score2 > score3) {
      document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = 2;
      document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "green");
      if (score1 > score3) {
        document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
        document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "red");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "red");
        document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = 3;
      document.getElementById("member-3").setAttribute("id", "green");
      if (score1 > score2) {
        document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
        document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "red");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("member-1").setAttribute("id", "red");
        document.getElementById("member-2").setAttribute("id", "yellow");
      }
    }
  }
  Set.clear();
}
```

```css
#member-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#member-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#member-3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#roll {
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#roll:hover {
  background-color: rgb(53, 52, 52);
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#parent {
  margin-left: 45%;
}

#winner {
  margin-left: -95px;
}

#green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}

#red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

#yellow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="winner">
    <h1>The Winner is team:-<span id="winnerteam"></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="member-1">
    <h1 id="score1"></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="member-2">
    <h1 id="score2"></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="member-3">

    <h1 id="score3"></h1>
  </div>
  <button id="roll">ROLL THE DICE</button>
  <!-- <a href="./index.html"></a> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Comment: `id` has nothing to do with CSS, it is a DOM attribute.  You need to be updating the `style` property.  e.g. `document.getElementById("member-1").style.background = 'blue'`.  You seem to have been given predefined classes to do that, so it's even easier: `document.getElementById("member-1").className = 'blue'`

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I suspect you want to `.setAttribute("class", "red")` instead of `.setAttribute("id", "red")` and change `#red` to `.red` in the css. Once you updated an element's `id`, you'll no longer be able to get it by that `id` because the `id` has been changed.

Comment: After you have changed all the ids from member-x to someColor, the code that looks for ids member-x won't find them any more.

Comment: thank you so much its resolved by change .setAttribute("class", "red") instead of .setAttribute("id", "red")

Answer (score -1):

removed all the color properties in CSS.because even if you do it with set `setAttribute("class", "red")` instead of `id` you would still need to remove those classes when the numbers change.because of `CSS Equal Specificity` meaning the latest rule wins - If the same rule is written twice into the external style sheet, then the latest rule wins.

so,instead of giving class i just styled the `.members` in `JS` with `.style.backgroundColor = "red";` etc.

```js
document.getElementById("roll").addEventListener("click", rollTheDice)

    function rollTheDice() {
        var score1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        document.getElementById("score1").innerText = score1;
        var score2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        document.getElementById("score2").innerText = score2;
        var score3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        document.getElementById("score3").innerText = score3;
        if (score1 === score2 && score2 == score3) {
            document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = "Draw";
            document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        } else if (score1 === score2 || score1 === score3 || score2 === score3) {
            if (score1 === score2) {
                document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = "Draw";
                document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                if (score3 > score1) {
                    document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            } else if (score1 === score3) {
                document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = "Draw";
                document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                if (score2 > score1) {
                    document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }
            } else if (score2 === score3) {
                document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = "Draw";
                document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                if (score1 > score2) {
                    document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (score1 > score2 && score1 > score3) {
                document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = 1;
                document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                if (score2 > score3) {
                    document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            } else if (score2 > score1 && score2 > score3) {
                document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = 2;
                document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                if (score1 > score3) {
                    document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("winnerteam").innerText = 3;
                document.getElementById("member-3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                if (score1 > score2) {
                    document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                    document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("member-1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    document.getElementById("member-2").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
#member-1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #member-2 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #member-3 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #roll {
        margin-left: -35px;
        margin-top: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        background-color: gray;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    #roll:hover {
        background-color: rgb(53, 52, 52);
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #parent {
        margin-left: 45%;
    }

    .winner {
        margin-left: -95px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="winner">
    <h1>The Winner is team:<span id="winnerteam"></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="member-1">
    <h1 id="score1"></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="member-2">
    <h1 id="score2"></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="member-3">

    <h1 id="score3"></h1>
  </div>
  <button id="roll">ROLL THE DICE</button>
  <!-- <a href="./index.html"></a> -->
</div>
```